# DC Demote left behind NTDS for the DC in Sites and Services. How can I fix this?

Tags: windows, active-directory, windows-server-2016, domain-controller

Recently demoted a RODC using the demote wizard with no issues or errors. The DC is now a member server and was removed from the DC's OU. There is still an entry for it in Sites and Services however, including the NTDS record. The AD replication status tool, when run, still thinks the server is a DC because it is included in the list and returns a replication status error.

I left it for 24 hours to see if it would clear up, but it is still there. Can I delete the record? Shouldn't the demote wizard have removed these settings? The DC was not forcibly removed.

Comment: **Can I delete the record?** - Yes.

Answer (score 1):

`Can I delete the record?`.

Yes. Deleting the DC object in AD Users and Computers/AD Sites and Services are supported methods of removing metadata of former domain controllers.

https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/identity/ad-ds/deploy/ad-ds-metadata-cleanup